# Генерация случайного числа от 0.01 до 1 в bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, случайные-числа

Есть скрипт отправки 300 транзакций:

- с суммой `$amount`от 1 до 10
- с комиссией `$fee` от 0 до 1
- и с задержкой от 30 до 200 секунд между транзакциями

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ">>>>>>>>Start Sending Transaction<<<<<<<<"
echo ""

for ((i = 0 ; i < 300 ; i++)); do
    amount=$((1 + $RANDOM % 10))

    fee=$(( $RANDOM %100 ))
    fee=$( bc <<< "scale=9;$fee/100" )
    echo "In" $i "Transaction sending" $amount "with fee" $fee

    send-payment -amount $amount \
         -receiver B23131424 -fee $fee -sender B324234234
    sleep $[ (30 + $RANDOM % 200 ) ]s
echo "----------------------------"
done
```

Диапазон чисел от 0 до 1:

```
fee=$(( $RANDOM %100 ))
fee=$( bc <<< "scale=9;$fee/100" )
```

Мне нужно чтобы минимальный диапазон был от 0.01 и максимально до 1.
Подскажите какие есть варианты.

Comment: 1. метки shell и bash, вообще-то, взаимоисключающие. 2. вопрос вообще-то про математику, а не про bash: как диапазон от `0` до `x` преобразовать в диапазон от `n` до `m`. 3. вопрос замусорен огромным количеством не имеющей отношения к вопросу информации. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin С каких пор shell и bash — взаимоисключающая пара?

Comment: А чем, написанное вами `fee=$( bc <<< "scale=9;$fee/100" )` не устраивает? Ну, может  0.01 стоит еще прибавить